# How to create an Android custom MediaCas plugin?

Tags: android, plugins, drm, television, widevine

I'm trying to add an Android custom MediaCas plugin but it's not clear how to do handle that.
The MediaCas.Session appears to be a final class and can't be extended.

Any documentation, example code or open source code that demonstrate how to create it ?

I see under this link two example plugins:

- clearkey
- mock

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_av/tree/489bfc236b5639f869850784d4122d7cd4f191b2/drm/mediacas/plugins

but it's not clear how to integrate in an app or elsewhere.